# Delete em sql - Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Como é a sintaxe de uma query usando Inner Join delete em sql, para comparar código de duas tabelas e excluir ser for igual?

Tabela itemVenda. na tabela itemvenda foi registrado uma venda cuja, o código é 4. Para executar o estorno, se for o caso, o usuário pode remover.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela controleCaixa. Quando estornar, o registro da tabela itemvenda será removido e ao mesmo tempo será removido, o registro cujo codDoc = 4. Este código do documento é gerado quando a venda é finalizada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: utilize um sub-select

Comment: poste a estrutura das suas tabelas e a query que precisa para te ajudarmos

Comment: Segue a estrutura da tabela. Preciso de uma query usando Inner Join delete em sql, para comparar código de duas tabelas e excluir ser for igual.

Comment: @JosueSantos: o gerenciador de banco de dados é MySQL ou SQL Server? As duas tags estão definidas. // É para estornar somente um item da venda ou toda a venda? // Além das tabelas `itemVenda` e `controleCaixa`, há a tabela `venda`?

Comment: José, existe a tabela venda também. Neste caso consegui resolver estornando um item da venda e excluir, o registro do controle do caixa deixando, só o registro na tabela venda. Resolvi com a ajuda do Rovann abaixo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Na sua situação, o recomendado seria uma FK com Cascade on delete, o banco irá se encarregar de fazer isso.

Mas ainda assim se não for utilizar os recursos do banco, no comando, imagino quer você irá executar algo do tipo:

```
"Delete from Vendas where Codigo = 4;"
```

Sendo assim, deveria executar os seguintes comandos:

```
Delete from controleCaixa where codDoc = 4;
Delete from itemVenda where venda =4;
Delete from venda where codigo = 4;
```

todos na mesma transação.

Comment: Rovann, neste caso consegui resolver estornando um item da venda e excluir, o registro do controle do caixa deixando, só o registro na tabela venda. Resolvi utilizando Delete from controleCaixa where codDoc = 4;  Obrigado!